# How to configure .htacces for Slim in subfolder and alias redirect

Tags: .htaccess, slim

My files **structure**:

```
-www  
-- .htaccess  
-- domains/  
--- someAlias.com/  
---- indexOfOtherWebsite.html  
--- otherAlias.com/  
---- indexOfAnotherWebsite.html  
-- angularApp/  
-- restSlim/  
--- .htaccess  
--- index.php
```

I am using **.htaccess** generated by my webhosting provider which allows me to run different websites for aliases:

```
# htaccess rules for subdomains and aliases
# to create web for alias, create a folder www/domains/(whole domain name)

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

This is a .htacces file from Slim documentation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ www/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) wwww/$1 [L]
```

which I tested Slim app is working fine when index.php and .htaccess itself is placed in web root(www). Then I moved it to separate folder(restSlim) and changed **.htaccess** file to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ www/restSlim/     [L]
RewriteRule (.*) wwww/restSlim/$1 [L]
```

I want the Slim application to run from subfolder(restSlim) without breaking functionality of web for alias. How should I edit those .htaccess files?

Answer (score 1):

I have made it working after all. File structure is the same just delete .htaccess from restSlim folder and keep only one in www and edit it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(restSlim) restSlim/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

First part solves Slim working from subdirectory and it should be last rule executed because of L flag. And the rest is the same like it was, making those webs for aliases possible.